# Use 'new' without 'xyz = new abc'

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a class as follows:

```
package org.requiredinput.rpg1.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import org.requiredinput.rpg1.Rpg1;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config =
            new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.title = "Awesome rpg";
        config.width = 800;
        config.height = 480;
        new LwjglApplication(new Rpg1(), config);
    }   
}
```

My question is - on the last line, the `new` statement is used without being preceded by an `=`.
What is being created? A new `LwjglApplication` object? Class?

And why doesn't it need to be instantiated like `app = new LwjglApplication()` for example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code creates a new object and doesn't give it a name, which means that it can't be used by `main()` afterwards. The code in the constructor will still run, and an object of type `LwjglApplication` will still be created. `main()` won't hold a reference to it, though.

This is just like when you call a function that returns a value without assigning it to a variable:

```
int foo() {
    System.out.println("Ron Paul 2016!");
    return 42;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    foo(); // will print out "Ron Paul 2016!" (w/o quotes)
}
```

Here, nothing is being done with the return value from `foo()` but the `println()` call will still run.

This is commonly used when the constructor (in this case, that of `LwjglApplication`) has a beneficial side-effect. In your specific case, a window is being popped up as a result of the constructor. (As [RafazZ said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27159304/1757964), you don't need to access the object that's being constructed because there are other ways to access it, provided through the third-party vendor's API.)

As Drew Kennedy mentioned in a comment, this pattern is also used for single-use objects.

Let's say you have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
    void bar() {
        // stuff that requires being in an instance, such as...
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        (new Foo()).bar();
    }
}
```

Note that the program doesn't bother assigning a name to the newly created `Foo` object, since it's only being used for the benefit of calling its `bar()` method.

Comment: It's also beneficial when you need to use that object only once in a block of code. No need to have the variable name saved in memory.

Comment: "Your code creates a new object and then immediately throws it away." That's not correct at all. Neither the object itself, nor the specific reference to it are "thrown" away. It is created, given to LwjglApplication, which in turn stores it internally. Nothing here is instantly being thrown away (= garbage collectable).

Comment: @noone How on earth is the specific reference not being thrown away? It gets popped off the callstack as a local as soon as `main()` terminates. However, I will revise that sentence to indicate that the object is not garbage collectable as a consequence of this.

Comment: @APerson Well, "immediately" != "as soon as main() terminates". That's what bothered me, I guess.

Comment: That statement is right at the end of main(), so why shouldn't they be equal?

Comment: @APerson Because there's still the constructor call of `new LwjglApplication` in between-

Comment: @noone I have thought about it for nearly four years, and you are correct. :p

Comment: I have been waiting for so long! At last, we have resolved this discussion. :P

Answer (score 2):

According to the BadLogic documentation, LwjglApplication creates a lightweight fullscreen window. This is sometimes done when designing stuff like games - you create a window, and then forget about it, because you don't need to modify it explicitly. You can still modify it using other methods - for that you need to get more familiar with the API provided by the vendor (BadLogic in your case).

[Here is a top level description for LwjglApplication.](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplication.html)

TL;DR UPDATE: Once `DesktopLauncher` is called it will create an OpenGL fullscreen window object by calling `new LwjglApplication`. Every time you call an OpenGL method, it will assume that you are implying the object that was created in the `DesktopLauncher`.

Answer (score 1):

An LwjglApplication object is being created, but not ASSIGNED to a variable.

So essentially you can't access it later. But it exists.

Comment: At least, it exists until it's garbage-collected.

Comment: Oh, I guess its name implies that its an application, so its kinda the 'top level container' and you don't need to access it, it just maybe dies when the window its in is killed?

Answer (score 1):

An object is being created but you are not assigning it a label. It is very likely the author is just interested in calling LwjglApplication constructor.

Contrary with what others have stated, the object created is not necessarily up for garbage collection. There are a few ways the object can actually stay alive depending on the particular object, e.g., Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

`new MyClass()` is a constructor call syntax in Java. Constructor is a special method, which returns a constructed object. It has some nuanses, but generally can be regarded as just method call.

So `new` without assignments is just calling a function and not using it's return value.

It is possible for all functions in Java (not to use return value).

The reason can be side effects, for example. Thus constructor may register it's result in some global static list.

If return value is an object and it is really not used, then it will be garbage collected later, as with every unused object.

Example:

```
package tests;

public class Runner {

    public static class Line {
        public Line(String line) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Line("Hello world");

    }

}
```